# WordPressの引っ越しphpエラーについて

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPressの引っ越し（サーバー・別ドメイン）をプラグインを使用せずに試しています。
下記のサイトを参考にデータベースとサーバーのデータを移行し最後にSearch and Replace for WordPress Databases Scriptにて作業をしましたが、ここで【dry run】したところ、actionでエラーがでてしまいました。
https://site-hikkoshi.com/1006/

下記エラー内容ですが、こちらのエラーはどのように修正したらいいでしょうか。ご教授のほど、よろしくお願いします。

```
The dry-run option was selected. No replacements will be made.

2: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ato2/www/xxxxxxxx.com/wp-config.php:1) in /home/ato2/www/xxxxxxxx.com/Search-Replace-DB-master/index.php on line 419

2: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ato2/www/xxxxxxxx.com/wp-config.php:1) in /home/ato2/www/xxxxxxxx.com/Search-Replace-DB-master/index.php on line 426
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp-config.php` をWindowsのメモ帳などで編集したりしていませんか？多くの場合、これはそれによって余計なBOMが挿入されることによって発生します。

BOM有無を扱えるエディタでBOMなしのUTF-8(UTF-8Nなどと表記される場合あり)で保存してください。